# image preprocessing with python: Lab <-> rgb

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I want to write a network which works with images. For it I need to convert rgb to Lab, work with it and convert back: Lab to rgb. At first I wanted to test how it works:

```
from skimage import io, color
rgb = io.imread(filename)
lab = color.rgb2lab(rgb)
rgb2 = color.lab2rgb(lab)
```

And I see that all components of rgb2 don't correspond to rgb:

```
In [5]: arr_rgb
Out[5]: 
array([[[  2.34194446e-17,   3.92156863e-03,   0.00000000e+00],
    [  7.84313725e-03,   1.56862745e-02,   1.17647059e-02],
    [  1.96078431e-02,   2.74509804e-02,   2.35294118e-02],
    ..., 
    [  1.09803922e-01,   1.68627451e-01,   1.56862745e-01],
    [  1.45098039e-01,   2.03921569e-01,   1.92156863e-01],
    [  1.37254902e-01,   1.96078431e-01,   1.84313725e-01]]


In [6]: image
Out[6]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   0],
    [  2,   4,   3],
    [  5,   7,   6],
    ..., 
    [ 28,  43,  40],
    [ 37,  52,  49],
    [ 35,  50,  47]],
```

Comment: skimage can store images in various dtypes.  If you convert both images to floating point format with `skimage.img_as_float`, your results should be close. See also http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html

Comment: Oooh, you are right! They are really very very close. =) But how can I move them all back to int?  skimage.img_as_int doesn't work.

Comment: `skimage.img_as_ubyte` or `skimage.img_as_uint`.